# Generalized Tannakian Duality?

Tags: braided-tensor-categories, tannakian-category

By the classical theory of Tannakian duality we know that every $k$-linear rigid abelian tensor category ($k$ a field) which has a fibre functor to $\mathrm{Vec}_k$ (finite dim. vector spaces over $k$) is equivalent to the category of representations of an affine group scheme over $k$ (or equivalently the category of comodules over a commutative Hopf algebra in $\mathrm{Vec}_k$ ).

I'm interested in the more general case where one has a "good" tensor category $C$ with a fibre functor to another "good" tensor category $D$ (instead of $\mathrm{Vec}_k$ ). What happens in this case? Is $C$ equivalent to the category of  comodules over a Hopf algebra in $D$? If yes, how this Hopf algebra can be constructed?

As an example consider this two special cases:

1- $\mathrm{PHS}_\mathbb{Q} \to \mathrm{Vec}^\bullet_\mathbb{Q}$: weight grading functor,

2- $\mathrm{MHS}_\mathbb{Q} \to \mathrm{PHS}_\mathbb{Q}$: sum of graded quotients functor.

Comment: The magic word here would be Barr-Beck: see http://member.ipmu.jp/scott.carnahan/pretalbot/pre-Talbot2.pdf

Comment: Not sure if this is the kind of generality you want but Daniel Schappi has defined a notion of "weakly Tannakian" where the target category are $B$-modules and characterized these guys as, roughly, categories of coherent sheaves on some stack. The references are: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2764v1.pdf and http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6358

Answer (score 3):

Majid has such theorems. The target category $\mathcal{D}$ is assumed to be braided monoidal (with duals if required). One good place to look is chapter 9.4.2 in his book "Foundations of Quantum Groups".

If you care about non-strict monoidal categories $\mathcal{C}$, another good place is his paper "Tannaka-Krein Theorem for Quasi-Hopf Algebras and other Results". He doesn't do the quasi-Hopf algebra case in the generality of braided monoidal categories but I am convinced this generalizes.

One cannot always have an equivalence of categories of $\mathcal{C}$ with the obtained module category of modules over a (quasi)Hopf or bialgebra $B$ in $\mathcal{D}$ but there is a universal choice, denote by $B-\mathbb{Mod}(\mathcal{D})$. It is important to note that that one needs to assume representability of the functores $Nat(-\otimes F^{\otimes n},F^{\otimes n})\colon \mathcal{D}\to \mathbb{Set}$ by $B^{\otimes n}$ in a compatible way.
I guess this is somehow a case of Barr-Beck (with extra structure) as hinted in a comment, but I don't know exactly how. In this case, there is a functor $\mathcal{C}\to B-\mathbb{Mod}(\mathcal{D})$ over $\mathcal{D}$. This functor is universal in the sense that whenever $B'$ is another bialgebra with the same property, then there exists a map $B'\to B$ and the diagram with the functor it induces commutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Lawrence Breen's survey in the Motives proceedings: *Tannakian categories* [1]. In general tensor functors $C \to D$ induce a morphisms between the corresponding gerbes.

If you have a “usual” fibre functor from $D$ to $\mathrm{Vec}_{k}$, you get a morphism of the associated Tannakian groups. In your first example that would be a morphism $\mathbb{G}\mathrm{m} \to \mathrm{MT}$. (Here $\mathrm{MT}$ is the proalgebraic Mumford–Tate group corresponding to all of $\mathrm{PHS}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. It's the limit over all “usual” MT-groups.)

I'm not sure if this satisfies your needs. After all, it is not exactly what you suggest you are looking for. So, alternatively, you might want to look at Deligne's *Catégories tannakiennes* [2]. In it he does some algebraic geometry internal to a Tannakian category. Maybe you can use this in your setup, so that $C$ gives rise to an affine group scheme in $D$. But I really didn't think about the details; this is just a vague suggestion.

---

[1] *Tannakian categories*, in Motives, Proc. Symp. Pure Math. 55 part 1, 337-376 (1994)

[2] *Catégories tannakiennes* in Grothendieck Festschrift vol II. Progress in Mathematics. 87 ( Birkhäuser Boston 1990) pp. 111–195. You can find it at the IAS website: http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/60_categoriestanna.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10998-017-0213-0) is devoted to the generalization of Tannakian formalism for fiber functors over more general tensor categories: $F:\cal{C}\to \cal{D}$. One can see easily that for representing $F$ as a forgetful functor, the existence of a "section" $s:\cal{D}\to \cal{C}$ is necessary.

Corollary 5.3 in the paper (which is an immediate corollary of a theorem in Deligne's "Categories Tannakiennes") shows that under the condition of the existence of the section, the required Hopf algebra (or equivalently "affine group scheme") exists if we assume that $\cal{C}$ and $\cal{D}$ are tensor categories over a field with characteristic zero and $F$ is also a tensor functor.

There  is also another approach in the paper which gives a similar result but  assumes  $\cal{C}$ and $\cal{D}$ are $k$-tensor categories over a field $k$, and $\cal{D}$ is semisimple, the existence of section for $F$ and  some other technical conditions. But there is no restriction on $k$.